# Techan.js - How to format time for weekly, monthly candlestick chart?

Tags: d3.js, techan.js

Following the [techanJS](https://github.com/andredumas/techan.js) [example](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/27c4a333b0e0813e093d) I was able to create candlestick charts with day data. But documentation does not shows how to format date for weekly, monthly and yearly candlestick or ohlc charts.

How to create weekly, monthly or yearly candlestick, ohlc chart with with techan JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the following format.

1. For week candlestick use week start day as candlestick date.
2. For month candlestick use first day of the month as candlestick date and so on..